# Intercept *all* requests from Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, chromium, nsurlprotocol

The title says it all. I would like to know about **everything** what the `WebView` is asking for. Some weird limitations like not knowing about XHR POST are not acceptable. In other words, something like iOS have in [`NSURLProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That one is application-wide hook. I don't need such level of control, `WebView`-instance-specific hook would be good enough. Now, i know that nothing like that exists on Android out of the box. I know about [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) and [`shouldInterceptRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)), but it's largely unusable. I need to know about **requests** (method, HTTP version, headers, you know) not just merely the URL strings. Moreover the intercepting is awkwardly synchronous. What happens if `shouldInterceptRequest` call is blocked because i need to ask a different server for related resource? It appears to me being designed just for a local resource caching.

On the other hand, i am willing to throw anything at the problem. Some kind of native library, hooking into low level internals? Extending Chromium interfaces with help of an existing project ([pwnall](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview), [mogoweb](https://github.com/mogoweb/chromium_webview))? Reflecting into the existing webkit class privates? Application-specific proxy? Any insights appreciated. I have read through two dozens of existing SO questions. They all either suggest a partial hack (like working around XHR POST deficiency with JavaScript) or it goes unresponded altogether, very often.

Comment: Long-term, you can see if [Mozilla's GeckoView](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView) might have more hooks for what you're seeking. The only one of your listed solutions that I would put much faith in would be the proxy.

Comment: @CommonsWare: with all respect to Mark Finkle, GeckoView appears to be quite dead horse. It seems to have stalled about a year ago. My listing isn't authoritative, rather a storm of wild thoughts for Android senior brains. So an app-specific proxy should be possible? What's the Google spell for more informations? :)

Comment: I searched on `android webview proxy`. Note that this is not supported, but it is more likely to be more stable than the other options in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Try with inspeckage:

https://github.com/ac-pm/Inspeckage

It needs Xposed and root access to work. I've been able to see WebView requests from apps. Im figuring out how to recreate them with Python's requests module.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The required functionality had to be Playstore publishable, so rooting wouldn't be an option. But thanks for the feedback anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal - try:

*WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);*

Open Chrome and go to url *chrome://inspect/#devices*

for details:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Anyway i was looking for programmatic control, not Chrome debugging.